# Drupal 7 Panels - Template sort of?

Tags: 7, panels

I am wondering if there is a way to say have a link under add content which automatically adds a panel layout with certain "options" selected and automatically adds blank custom content slates?

Something that would make it easier for a user editing it to click a single link and not have to type in

Title, Menu Link, save -> click Panel Content -> Add the mini panel top right, add the new custom content top left, add the new custom content middle.

Something that would allow me to click

Add New Article

Fill in title, menu link, click save, and be sent to the panel content area with all the panel content slates already added, you just need to edit them.

Sorry if that is confusing :)